# Manga where main character not good with combat have to do chores for living, get hired by a party or guild to manage house do chores

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am looking for a specific fantasy Manga where the main character,is a support type character not suitable for combat maybe an alchemist or support magician has to do chores to survive. He helps a group of adventurer manage their house and with his help, the adventurer group become better, but most member of the group doesn't see his contribution and kick him out so he work for another group. The group of adventurers is either called a party or a guild.

Comment: This is a very common setup - main character has some unconventional or seemingly-useless skill, gets kicked out of a party of adventurers, turns out he was the primary reason for their earlier success. Do you remember any other details? e.g. what the new group is like? Or anything about the first group? Was he kicked out of his first party in the first chapter of the manga? And do you mean he literally managed a house, or is that just a general term for doing chores?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I remember he was cleaning house and other support related things. Not really kicked out of party, more a party leader hired him to do chores and support related work, but other members don't like, soon he leave to work for another group.

Answer (score 1):

I got you. Cheat na Tablet wo Motte Kaiteki Isekai Seikatsu/Living Comfortably In A Different World With A Cheat Tablet. According to [Anilist](https://anilist.co/manga/140718/Cheat-na-Tablet-wo-Motte-Kaiteki-Isekai-Seikatsu):

> Kento Yamazaki is an ordinary young man who found himself reincarnated in another world with a tablet in his hand! Kento hones his housekeeping skills, making full use of the tablet's apps to cook delicious dishes and clean up dirty messes in the shortest time. Eventually, he joins the adventurer party "Akatsuki," whose members include a beautiful elf, a quiet but handsome bespectacled boy, and many other unique characters.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you [edit] this to explain how this series matches the details provided in the question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve your answer by providing a synopsis of this manga, and some links if available.